# How to Install WordPress SQL Server?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a volunteering web designer and a client has given me the details to ftp to upload the website i have created for them.  For the hosting they only have SQL Server not MySQL.  There account won't allow me to create a MySQL database, without upgrading(more money) and this is a volunteer position.  How do i install WordPress with SQL Server?

Comment: What is the `OS` on server ?

Comment: It says Windows starter hosting?

Answer (score 0):

### It's a long step by step task:

At first you need to install the [WordPress on SQL Server](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/download) version of `WordPress` and then follow the steps on [Installing WordPress on SQL Server](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server). Also check [Getting Started.](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/getting-started)

Comment: Does this version have "custom fields" and can i still use plugins?

Comment: Yes, that is just another version for `MS`.

Comment: Use plugins, yes, but keep in mind that there are plenty of plugins that are only compatible with MySQL as that is the only database officially supported by WordPress (though I use MariaDB as a drop in replacement)

Comment: You should drop the link (MariaDB) then.

Comment: What is a drop in replacement?

Comment: Dude! Provide the link here, sorry for the mis-confusions :p

Comment: Have you got anything so far ?

Comment: this page not working, will you have another for consultation? @TheAlpha